# Virtual destructor of abstract class fix is fuzzy

Tags: c++, qt

I have an abstract class and I get some errors when I try to delete the instance of that class.

```
class CCobjectBase
{
public:
    CCobjectBase();
    virtual ~CCobjectBase();

    virtual void createPainterPath() = 0;
};

class CTriangle : public CCobjectBase
{
public:
    CTriangle();
    ~CTriangle();
    void createPainterPath();
  };

CCobjectBase :: ~CCobjectBase(){}
```

I create the object as bellow:

```
std::vector<CCobjectBase *> m_objectBaseList;

m_objectBaseList.push_back(new CTriangle());

//do stuff with m_objectBaseList

delete m_objectBaseList.at(index);
m_objectBaseList.erase(m_objectBaseList.begin() + index);
```

I retrieve an error at `~CTriangle()` "undefined reference to CCobjectBase :: ~CCobjectBase()". If I delete the virtual destructor from CCobjectBase I get the warning "deleting object of abstract class type CCobjectBase which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behavior" that is really annoying but the fix cause more problems.

**UPDATE:**
This is kind of stupid but i tried Run qmake -> rebuild all and nothing happen but when I restart the app there was no errors or warnings displayed. Why it works now? I do not know.

Comment: Did you implement the declared destructor?

Comment: It is a linker error: definition of given function cannot be found: Do you define it, or do you link with the file defining it ?

Comment: `virtual ~CCobjectBase() = default;` is probably what you need.

Comment: Yes I implemented it: CCobjectBase :: ~CCobjectBase(){}

Comment: [OT]: Avoid raw owning pointer, prefer smart pointer, and so `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CCobjectBase>> m_objectBaseList;`

Comment: Your class declarations miss a final `;`: `class CCobjectBase {...};`. Adding an empty definition to all your non-pure virtual method, your code is compiling with [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90ff089371a7be51).

Comment: I know. Sorry about that . I have around 30 functions and I put here just the first one and I forget to close the class properly.

Answer (score 3):

Your method

```
virtual ~CCobjectBase();
```

is undefined. It is declared, but you didn't provide definition.
With C++11 you can change declaration to

```
virtual ~CCobjectBase() = default;
```

for an empty definition.

Comment: I mention it in a previous comment that I implemented it. This does not seems to fix my problem.

Comment: @student Then, probably, you definition is not getting linked together with code, in which CObjectBase::~CObjectBase is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I get it to compile with `clang++` when I substitute the following definitions:

```
#include <vector>

class CCobjectBase
{
public:
    CCobjectBase() {};
    virtual ~CCobjectBase() {};

    virtual void createPainterPath() = 0;
};

class CTriangle : public CCobjectBase
{
public:
    CTriangle();
    ~CTriangle();
    void createPainterPath();
};

CTriangle::CTriangle() {}

CTriangle::~CTriangle() {}

void CTriangle::createPainterPath() {}

int main() {
  std::vector<CCobjectBase *> m_objectBaseList;

  m_objectBaseList.push_back(new CTriangle());

  //do stuff with m_objectBaseList

  int index = 0;
  delete m_objectBaseList.at(index);
  m_objectBaseList.erase(m_objectBaseList.begin() + index);
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, please provide more information.

Comment: Now seems to work after I restart the application. But this is not making any sense. Why it was not working when a Run qmake and rebuild all the data?

Comment: I don't know what `Run qmake` means; I assume you're using a compiler system I'm not familiar with. I'd guess, based on experience, that you have a makefile with incorrect dependencies, so something isn't getting recompiled unless everything gets cleaned out. But that's such a wild guess I can't honestly say.